# Where to find luna safenet client logs?

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm, gemalto

We are using luna SDK to develop algorithms to perform cryptographic operations using HSM. In doing so, we installed Luna client software in our application. The problem is I am not able to find the logs generated by the client software. After my search, I found cklog.txt contains the logs but I can't find this file on the client installation.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you can find cklog.txt in your luna client installation folder.

```
eg : C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cklog.txt
```

If you don't find, you need to check the configuration file if you have the below entry:

Windows:

```
C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\crystoki.ini

[CkLog2]
Enabled=1
NewFormat=1
File=C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cklog.txt
FileSize=100
Error=C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cklog_error.txt
LibNT32=C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\win32\cryptoki.dll
LibNT=C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cryptoki.dll
```

Linux:

```
/etc/Chrystoki.conf

CkLog2 = {
    LibUNIX=/usr/lib/libCryptoki2.so;
    LibUNIX64=/usr/lib/libCryptoki2_64.so
    Enabled=1;
    File=/usr/safenet/lunaclient/cklog.txt;
    Error=/usr/safenet/lunaclient/error.txt;
    NewFormat=1;
    LoggingMask=ALL_FUNC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I can understand. But I am using Linux. Do you know where can I find the config for the linux luna client setup. I have looked at my setup, I dont find crystoki.ini file.